# Adding net-snmp package to poky yocto fails

Tags: yocto, bitbake, net-snmp, openembedded

I'm having trouble adding the net-snmp package to my poky krogoth 2.1 build. I've successfully added a few extra packages such as rpm and gdb by editing the conf/local.conf and adding them to the CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL line but I'm unable to get 'net-snmp' to work. When I do, I get an error such as below:

`[build]$ bitbake core-image-full-cmdline
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 179, in wrapped
    return func(fn, *args)
  File "/work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 203, in parse_config_file
    return bb.parse.handle(fn, data, include)
  File "/work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 113, in handle
    return h['handle'](fn, data, include)
  File "/work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 124, in handle
    abs_fn = resolve_file(fn, data)
  File "/work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 136, in resolve_file
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, "file %s not found" % fn)
IOError: [Errno 2] file /work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/meta-networking/conf/layer.conf not found
ERROR: Unable to parse /work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/meta-networking/conf/layer.conf: [Errno 2] file /work/poky.git-krogoth-2_1/meta-networking/conf/layer.conf not found`

The error seems to indicate that it's unable to find a meta-networking layer. So I guess ultimately my question is how can I get this layer added to my Poky system. I've had trouble finding any resources on where to download this layer so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This errors says that You provided path incorrectly in conf/bblayers.conf for this meta-networking/ layer - please double check or provide this bblayers.conf file.

Comment: Add the `meta-networking` into `conf/bblayers.conf`. `meta-networking` belongs to `meta-openembedded`. So you can clone it and add it to `bblayers.conf` by manually editing it or using `bitbake-layers add-layer <full_path>/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/`. This command will parse all recipes inside it and add the layer in `bblayers.conf` under the variable `BBLAYERS`.

Comment: This was the issue. I hadn't added the layer the correct way and I didn't download the krogoth version of the 'meta-openembeded-master' layer on top of that. Thanks!

Comment: if you got answer for your q? you have to post solution. not comments like this. then others will find the sol easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by obtaining the krogoth version of meta-openembedded and adding the meta-networking layer into conf/bblayers.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Download the krogoth version of the `'meta-openembeded-master'` layer on top of that